# Ubuntu Installation (Dual-boot, host, or USB)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I wanted to install Ubuntu (or maybe some other linux distro). So, I have a couple of questions. Is it possible to run your entire Ubuntu installation of a USB Flash Drive (What I mean is, is it possible to run Ubuntu without installing it forever using my USB Flash Drive). Or if it's not is it better to override an old pc with Windows 10 on it or Dual-boot it along with my new PC? And how do I do any of these options. Please explain all the steps involved including partitoning, how to install the distro, and how to switch between the different OS's. Also if I later decide that I don't need Ubuntu how do I delete it?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you can try out Ubuntu and its flavors without a need of installing it permanently on your hard drive. After you boot up from usb flash drive, you will have a prompt asking you if you want to install ubuntu or just play with it temporarily.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   You can install to thumb-drive, though some releases (and ISOs) are easier than others (Ubuntu and *flavors* have five supported installers chosen by the ISO used). You just delete the partition (after you've ensured another OS controls the boot process). But non-Ubuntu distros are off-topic here

Comment: If your computer has enough resources, more than 4GBs of ram, can use Ubuntu in a VM.  Can also install fully onto a USB, SD, external hard drive or even your internal drive if you have enough space.  Can also just use the Try Ubuntu option, but unless you set up persistence, all data added will be lost after a reboot.

Comment: Ok, so about what @crip659 said. You're saying it is possible to run Ubuntu on a separate external hard drive? Is that correct? Are the steps any different?

Comment: Steps are the same.  Download ISO, burn to USB stick to use as installer, and use install option.  You do need to make sure when installing you know which drive is which.  It is easy to install on wrong drive/partition and over write your important data